# Leetcode--3 find the longest substring without repeating character

Tags: string, algorithm, c++11

The target is simple--find the longest **substring** without repeating characters,here is the code:

```
 class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int ans = 0;
        int dic[256];
        memset(dic, -1, sizeof(dic));
        int len = s.size();
        int idx = -1;

        for (int i = 0;i < len;i++) {
            char c = s[i];
            if (dic[c] > idx)
                idx = dic[c];

            ans = max(ans, i - idx);

            dic[c] = i;
        }
        return ans;
    }

};
```

From its concise expression,I think this is a high-performance method,and we can get that its Time Complexity is just O(n).But I'm confused about this method,though I came up with some examples to understand,can anyone give some tips or idea to me?

Comment: Question is unclear. Could you elaborate? Did you try this, does it achieve your goal ? What are you asking for? Also: you tagged this C++11, but looks pretty much "C-style" to me.

Comment: @kebs As for c++11,I find that VS2015 supports this standard. But I want to emphasize that why I take this as a tag is just because I have a slip of a pen,maybe I should just change it for C++......acutally I didn't konw well about the differences between the C++'s standards

Answer (score 0):

What it is doing is recording the position where each character was last seen.
As you step through, it takes each new encountered character and the length of non-repeat goes back at least as far as that last-seen, but for future indices can't go back further, as we have now seen a duplicate.

So we are maintaining in idx, the start index of the latest-seen highest-starting duplicate, which is the candidate for the start of the longest non-duplicating sequence.

I'm certain that the `ans = max()` code code be optimised slightly, as after encountering a new duplicate, you have to go forward at least ans chars from the start of that duplicate before ans can be improved again. You still need to do the rest of the work maintaining dic and idx, but you could avoid that particular test for ans for a few iterations. You would have to do a lot of unrolling to benefit, though.

Comment: it seems that I have some thinking.And I think the  If Structure's function is if we can satisfy it,then the character currently has existed in the subing(return value)we maintain,so we may(cause  we should  also compare) throw away it,am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question in a single paragraph.